# Matching view colums to table columns using sys.tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I'm on a project using SQL server 2008. We load some data into a huge number of tables. For each of these tables a couple of views are created.
The first view, lets call it the Standard view, simply lists all columns in the table.

The second view, lets call it the custom view, only lists specific selected columns from the table. This view is needed due to business requirements. The selected columns are hand picked, **AND RENAMED**, etc.

Now I want to document this, by making an automatic extract of how all the columns on the two views and the table correlate to each other.
This is where the problems turn up.

I use the following SQL to make the list:

```
/* Run this for the DATABASE you want info on.  */

/* The first table lists all Tables and columns. */
with ListOfTableColumns as (
select 
       TheTables.name as 'TableName'
      ,TheColumns.name as 'ColumnName'
      ,TheColumns.column_id as 'ColumnNumber'

from sys.tables as TheTables   /* Find tables */ 
join sys.columns as TheColumns  /* Find columns from tables */
on TheColumns.object_id = TheTables.object_id

),

/* The second table contains all Custom views and columns. */
ListOfCustomViewColumns as (
SELECT
    object_name(d.object_id) as ViewName,
    c.name AS ViewColumn,
    isnull(type_name(c.system_type_id), t.name) AS DateType,
    object_name(d.referenced_major_id) as TableName,
    tablecols.name AS TableColumn
FROM 
    sys.views v
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = v.object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    JOIN sys.sql_dependencies d ON d.object_id = v.object_id 
        AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id
    JOIN sys.columns tablecols ON d.referenced_major_id = tablecols.object_id 
        AND tablecols.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id 
        AND tablecols.column_id = c.column_id
where v.schema_id = (select schema_id from sys.schemas where name = 'LZSDS') /* We only want the Custom views. */
),

/* The third table contains all Standard views and columns. */
ListOfStandardViewColumns as (
SELECT
    object_name(d.object_id) as ViewName,
    c.name AS ViewColumn,
    isnull(type_name(c.system_type_id), t.name) AS DateType,
    object_name(d.referenced_major_id) as TableName,
    tablecols.name AS TableColumn
FROM 
    sys.views v
    JOIN sys.columns c ON c.object_id = v.object_id
    LEFT JOIN sys.types t ON c.user_type_id = t.user_type_id
    JOIN sys.sql_dependencies d ON d.object_id = v.object_id 
        AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id
    JOIN sys.columns tablecols ON d.referenced_major_id = tablecols.object_id 
        AND tablecols.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id 
        AND tablecols.column_id = c.column_id
where v.schema_id = (select schema_id from sys.schemas where name = 'LZSVW') /* We only want the Custom views. */
)

/* Create the actual final list of Tables and Views. */
select
  ListOfTableColumns.TableName as 'Table_name'
 ,ListOfTableColumns.ColumnName as 'Table_column_name'
 ,ListOfTableColumns.ColumnNumber as 'Table_column_number'
 ,ListOfStandardViewColumns.ViewColumn as 'Standard_view_column_name'
 ,ListOfStandardViewColumns.ViewName as 'Standard_view_name'
 ,ListOfCustomViewColumns.ViewColumn as 'Custom_view_column_name'
 ,ListOfCustomViewColumns.ViewName as 'Custom_view_name'
from ListOfTableColumns
left join ListOfStandardViewColumns
on ListOfTableColumns.TableName = ListOfStandardViewColumns.TableName
and ListOfTableColumns.ColumnName = ListOfStandardViewColumns.TableColumn
left join ListOfCustomViewColumns
on ListOfTableColumns.TableName = ListOfCustomViewColumns.TableName
and ListOfTableColumns.ColumnName = ListOfCustomViewColumns.TableColumn
order by ListOfTableColumns.TableName, ListOfTableColumns.ColumnNumber
```

The above code is able to match the columns just fine... as long as the custom view has all the columns. As soon as some of them has been chosen not to be part of the view, they show up wrong in the extract.

Image of the problem can be seen here: http://pasteboard.co/2yqRNOj1.png

How do I make an extract from the sys.tables or INFORMATION_SCHEMA, that can match the columns properly?

In case you want some example code to set up tables for the problem, I have provided it below.
(You might need to change some of the schema names etc to fit your installation.)

```
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[LZS].[TBDLZLT000_TESTTABLE1]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [LZS].[TBDLZLT000_TESTTABLE1]
GO

CREATE TABLE [LZS].[TBDLZLT000_TESTTABLE1](
    [DWH_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [NUMERIC1] [decimal](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [NUMERIC2] [decimal](3, 0) NULL,
    [NUMERIC3] [decimal](3, 0) NULL,
    [VARCHAR1] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [VARCHAR2] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [VARCHAR3] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [UPDATE_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PKDLZLT000] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DWH_DATE] ASC,
    [NUMERIC1] ASC,
    [VARCHAR1] ASC,
    [UPDATE_TIMESTAMP] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Create Standard View 
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[LZSVW].[STANDARD_TEST_TABLE_VIEW]'))
DROP VIEW [LZSVW].[STANDARD_TEST_TABLE_VIEW]
GO

CREATE VIEW [LZSVW].[STANDARD_TEST_TABLE_VIEW] as select 
 * 
from LZS.TBDLZLT000_TESTTABLE1
;
GO


-- Create Custom View
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[LZSDS].[CUSTOM_TEST_TABLE_VIEW]'))
DROP VIEW [LZSDS].[CUSTOM_TEST_TABLE_VIEW]
GO

CREATE VIEW [LZSDS].[CUSTOM_TEST_TABLE_VIEW] as select 
 DWH_DATE 
,NUMERIC1 AS NUM1
,NUMERIC3 AS NUM3
,VARCHAR1 AS VC1
,VARCHAR3 AS VC3
,UPDATE_TIMESTAMP
from LZS.TBDLZLT000_TESTTABLE1
where DWH_DATE = (SELECT MAX(DWH_DATE) FROM LZS.TBDLZLT000_TESTTABLE1)
GO

IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[LZS].[TBDLZLT002_TESTTABLE2]') AND type in (N'U'))
DROP TABLE [LZS].[TBDLZLT002_TESTTABLE2]
GO

CREATE TABLE [LZS].[TBDLZLT002_TESTTABLE2](
    [DWH_DATE] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [NUMERIC1] [decimal](3, 0) NOT NULL,
    [NUMERIC2] [decimal](3, 0) NULL,
    [NUMERIC3] [decimal](3, 0) NULL,
    [VARCHAR1] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [VARCHAR2] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [VARCHAR3] [varchar](3) NULL,
    [UPDATE_TIMESTAMP] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PKDLZLT002] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [DWH_DATE] ASC,
    [NUMERIC1] ASC,
    [VARCHAR1] ASC,
    [UPDATE_TIMESTAMP] ASC
) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO

-- Create Standard View 
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[LZSVW].[STANDARD_TEST_TABLE2_VIEW]'))
DROP VIEW [LZSVW].[STANDARD_TEST_TABLE2_VIEW]
GO

CREATE VIEW [LZSVW].[STANDARD_TEST_TABLE2_VIEW] as select 
 * 
from LZS.TBDLZLT002_TESTTABLE2
;
GO


-- Create Custom View
IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.views WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[LZSDS].[CUSTOM_TEST_TABLE2_VIEW]'))
DROP VIEW [LZSDS].[CUSTOM_TEST_TABLE2_VIEW]
GO

CREATE VIEW [LZSDS].[CUSTOM_TEST_TABLE2_VIEW] as select 
 DWH_DATE
,NUMERIC1 AS NUM1
,NUMERIC2 AS NUM2
,NUMERIC3 AS NUM3
,VARCHAR1 AS VC1
,VARCHAR2 AS VC2
,VARCHAR3 AS VC3
,UPDATE_TIMESTAMP
from LZS.TBDLZLT002_TESTTABLE2
where DWH_DATE = (SELECT MAX(DWH_DATE) FROM LZS.TBDLZLT002_TESTTABLE2)
GO
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE, as below (based on your sample data):

```
;WITH TableColumnsLZS as 
(
    SELECT 
        s.name as 'SchemaName'
        ,t.name as 'TableName'
        ,c.name as 'ColumnName'
        ,c.column_id as 'ColumnNumber'
    FROM sys.tables as t
        INNER JOIN sys.columns as c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
        INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
    WHERE s.name = 'LZS'
)
, StandardViewColumnsLZSVW AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE AS UsedColumns 
    WHERE UsedColumns.VIEW_SCHEMA = 'LZSVW'
), 
CustomViewColumnsLZSDS AS
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE AS UsedColumns 
    WHERE UsedColumns.VIEW_SCHEMA = 'LZSDS'
)
SELECT LZS.TableName Table_name, 
    LZS.ColumnName Table_column_name,
    LZS.ColumnNumber Table_column_number,
    LZSVW.COLUMN_NAME Standard_view_column_name,
    LZSVW.VIEW_NAME Standard_view_name,
    LZSDS.COLUMN_NAME Custom_view_column_name,
    LZSDS.VIEW_NAME Custom_view_name
FROM TableColumnsLZS LZS
    LEFT JOIN StandardViewColumnsLZSVW LZSVW ON LZS.SchemaName = LZSVW.TABLE_SCHEMA AND LZS.TableName = LZSVW.TABLE_NAME AND LZS.ColumnName = LZSVW.COLUMN_NAME
    LEFT JOIN CustomViewColumnsLZSDS LZSDS ON LZS.SchemaName = LZSDS.TABLE_SCHEMA AND LZS.TableName = LZSDS.TABLE_NAME AND LZS.ColumnName = LZSDS.COLUMN_NAME
```

Which returns:
[image: this]

EDIT:

COLUMN_NAME in INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE gets the real name of the column, not the alias. Trying to join with INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS like below also did not work when the number of columns in the view is not equal to the one in the table because the ordinal_position is kept from the table level.

```
SELECT *
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS tc
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE vu on vu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
                                                         and vu.table_name = tc.table_name
                                                         and vu.column_name = tc.column_name
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS vc on vc.table_schema = vu.view_schema
                                                         and vc.table_name = vu.view_name
                                                         and tc.ordinal_position = vc.ordinal_position
    WHERE vu.VIEW_SCHEMA = 'LZSDS'
```

But this works:

```
 ;WITH TableColumnsLZS as 
    (
        SELECT 
            s.name as 'SchemaName'
            ,t.name as 'TableName'
            ,c.name as 'ColumnName'
            ,c.column_id as 'ColumnNumber'
        FROM sys.tables as t
            INNER JOIN sys.columns as c ON c.object_id = t.object_id
            INNER JOIN sys.schemas s ON t.schema_id = s.schema_id
        WHERE s.name = 'LZS'
    )
    , StandardViewColumnsLZSVW AS
    (
        SELECT * 
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE AS UsedColumns 
        WHERE UsedColumns.VIEW_SCHEMA = 'LZSVW'
    ), 
    OrdinalPositionCTE
    AS
    (
        SELECT vu.*, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vu.table_name ORDER BY ordinal_position) ordinal_position
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS tc
            INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE vu on vu.table_schema = tc.table_schema
                                                             and vu.table_name = tc.table_name
                                                             and vu.column_name = tc.column_name
        WHERE vu.VIEW_SCHEMA = 'LZSDS'
    ),
    CustomViewColumnsLZSDS
    AS
    (
        SELECT op.*, vc.COLUMN_NAME Alias
        FROM OrdinalPositionCTE op
        INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS vc on vc.table_schema = op.view_schema
                                                             and vc.table_name = op.view_name
                                                             and op.ordinal_position = vc.ordinal_position
    )
SELECT LZS.TableName Table_name, 
    LZS.ColumnName Table_column_name,
    LZS.ColumnNumber Table_column_number,
    LZSVW.COLUMN_NAME Standard_view_column_name,
    LZSVW.VIEW_NAME Standard_view_name,
    LZSDS.Alias Custom_view_column_name,
    LZSDS.VIEW_NAME Custom_view_name
FROM TableColumnsLZS LZS
    LEFT JOIN StandardViewColumnsLZSVW LZSVW ON LZS.SchemaName = LZSVW.TABLE_SCHEMA AND LZS.TableName = LZSVW.TABLE_NAME AND LZS.ColumnName = LZSVW.COLUMN_NAME
    LEFT JOIN CustomViewColumnsLZSDS LZSDS ON LZS.SchemaName = LZSDS.TABLE_SCHEMA AND LZS.TableName = LZSDS.TABLE_NAME AND LZS.ColumnName = LZSDS.COLUMN_NAME
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

However, while it looks like it works it seems to pick the names for the Custom view colums in a wrong way.

It displays the column names from the standard view (or from the table). Thus any renamed columns have the wrong name in the Custom_view_column_name result.

Is it possible to fix this?
Because I need it so that a user can lookup the custom name, and then find the real table column.

Comment: I have edited my answer to return the alias in the view instead of the column name. There's no simple solution for this, as far as I can see.

Comment: Thank you very much for this. It works perfectly.

Your solution has two features that I find very interesting.
One is that I had personally concluded that the INFORMATION_SCHEMA tables could not solve the problem for me, yet you find the solution anyway.

Second, even though you say there is no simply solution, I still find your solution with the alias pretty and easy to understand.